# dvb: is it possible to have audio and video in a single 188 byte packet?

Tags: dvb

To me this is not possible. But I can't be too sure. Can somebody confirm this? If it's possible, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. According to MPEG2 systems standard - each packet of Transport streams belongs to one PID - which is Packet ID - which correspond to unique component (either audio or video). Hence, it is not possible to put two stream data within 188 packets.